# Proving a version of Cauchy's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be continuous over $\mathbb{C}$ and  Holomorphic over $\mathbb{C} \setminus  \mathbb{R}$. Show that for every $\gamma$ - closed, simple, piecewise $C^1$(continuously differentiable) path :

$ \int_\gamma f(z)dz=0 $

I think that I need to modify the proof of Cauchy's theorem over a triangular path, but I have a really hard time doing that... any ideas?

Comment: Show that $f$ is entire first. Morera's theorem might be an idea.

Comment: The definition of entire that I learned , is that $f$ is Holomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$ , that is not true in this case.

Comment: @almog Actually, under the assumptions, $f$ is entire. That is most conveniently - in my opinion - shown via Morera's theorem. (And if the version of Morera's theorem that you learned is the one that wikipedia states as Morera's theorem, go straight to the section "weakening of the hypothesis"; **that** is the real thing.)

Comment: If you want to use Morera's theorem, how do you prove that for every triangular path $T$ , $\int_{T} f(z)dz=0$ ?

Comment: Show, using Cauchy's theorem,  that you can reduce the integral to a path that is very close to $\mathbb{R}$ and show using continuity that by chosing the path close enough that the remaining integral in close to zero.

Comment: let's say I succeeded (I'm still having trouble formalizing it) does this mean that :
there is no function that is  continuous over $\mathbb{C}$ , Holomorphic over $\mathbb{C} \setminus  \mathbb{R}$ and not Holomorphic in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, @almog, it does mean that. A continuous function that is holomorphic on the complement of a straight line is in fact holomorphic on that line too.

Comment: well, that's very interesting.... I will probably sleep about it and answer the question tomorrow. Hope you two could provide feedback. thank you :)

Comment: Did you manage to prove it, @almog?